# Access violation when loading ssl handler to Imap server in indy

Tags: delphi, ssl, imap, indy

I'm trying to assign a `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` to my `TIdImap4Server` but if I do that I get a memory leak afterwards because the `TIdImap4Server` assigns its own IOHandler internally.

1. So there is an `Access violation` when closing the program after I try this :

   `Imap4Server.IOHandler := mySSLIOHandler; 
   // mySSLIOHandler is from type TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL`
2. And there is `Access violation` if I try this :

   `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL(IMAP4Server.IOHandler).SSLOptions.CertFile := myCertFile; // or any other property of SSLOptions`

Can anyone suggest an answer for this problem ?

Comment: There is no way what you describe can happen if you are assigning the `Imap4Server.IOHandler` property before activating the server. I cannot produce the AV based on your description. Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the AV in action.

Answer (score 1):

Every TCP server component in Indy, including `TIdImap4Server`, uses whichever `TIdServerIOHandler...` object has been assigned to the server's `IOHandler` property **before** the server is activated.  An internal `TIdServerIOHandlerStack` object is created and assigned **only if** there is no `TIdServerIOHandler...` object already assigned at *activation time*.

So make sure that you are assigning `Imap4Server.IOHandler := mySSLIOHandler` *before* you set `Imap4Server.Active := True` (unless you are assigning them at design-time, which is safe to do as `Active=true` will not take effect until all DFM property values have finished streaming).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing - I assign the IOHandler before I set ``Imap4Server.Active := True;`` - I have never tried to assign ``TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL`` to a server after I have activated it - there are no problems with ``TIdSmtpServer`` and ``TIdPop3Server`` but this problem occurs with ``TIdImap4Server``.

Comment: Is there a way to assign ssl certificates to an IOHandler of type ``TIdServerIOHandlerStack`` (the internally assigned one) ?

Comment: There is no way that `TIdImap4Server` would create an internal `TIdServerIOHandler...` if one has already been assigned. `TIdImap4Server` is no different than `TIdSmtpServer` or `TIdPop3Server` in this regard, as the logic is managed by `TIdCustomTCPServer` for all TCP servers. I cannot reproduce the AV you have described. And the only way your SSLIOHandler would be leaked is if you are not freeing it yourself. Assigning `TIdIMAP4Server.IOHandler` will not take ownership. You would have to create the SSLIOHandler with `TIdIMAP4Server` as its `Owner` if you want it to be auto-freed.

Comment: And no, you cannot assign SSL certificates to the default `TIdServerIOHandlerStack`, as it does not implement SSL. That is why a separate `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` component exists for that purpose.